# Getting error invalid literal when saving model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have an issue when I try to save my form. Hope you can help me. A second thing maybe would be if you have a better solution to display a dropdown in my form. I build a function for it, but feels very ugly.

models.py

```
class BBQ(models.Model):
    bbq_brand = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    bbq_model = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bbq_brand


class CookSession(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bbq = models.ManyToManyField(BBQ, blank=True)
    cook_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    cook_description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cook_name
```

views.py

```
class AddCookView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'cooks/add_cook.html'
    form_class = AddCookForm
    success_url = '/cooks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(AddCookView, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
def get_bbq():
    bbqs = []
    bbq = BBQ.objects.all()
    for q in bbq:
        bbqs.append((q, q))
    print bbqs
    return bbqs


class AddCookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    bbq = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_bbq())

    class Meta:
        model = CookSession
        exclude = ['user']
```

FULL TRACE

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/add

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'cooks',
 'accounts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  56.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  222.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/src/cooks/views.py" in form_valid
  21.         form.save()

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  452.             self._save_m2m()

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _save_m2m
  434.                 f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in save_form_data
  1618.         setattr(instance, self.attname, data)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  481.         manager.set(value)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in set
  910.                     self.add(*new_objs)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in add
  843.                 self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in _add_items
  986.                             '%s__in' % target_field_name: new_ids,

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  790.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  808.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1243.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1269.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1199.             condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  19.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  56.                     self.lookup_name, self.rhs)

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  746.             return [self.get_prep_value(v) for v in value]

File "/Users/patrick/programming/django/itsmokes/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  976.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /add
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'r'
```

Comment: Post full traceback please.

Comment: Might have to do with you using the `BBQ` model's string representation as the form value. Try changing `bbqs.append((q, q))` to `bbqs.append((q.pk, q))`.